# Where is the Azure Storage library changelog?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm using the official [nuget package](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) of Windows Azure Storage Client Library to retrieve items of my Azure tables.

Recently I updated the package from version 2.0.2.0 to 2.0.5.0 and my app stopped working because the results returned by my storage query are different with the new version.

I'm looking for the library changelog in order to understand how to fix the issue.

Do you know where can I find it ?

The [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj721952.aspx) provided on the [nuget page](http://nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) seems to be outdated (it's a changelog between 1.x and 2.x, not between 2.0.2 and 2.0.5 !). Also, the Windows Azure Storage team's [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/) is not updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please refer to the [changelog.txt](https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/microsoft-azure-api/Services/Storage/changelog.txt) that is always updated with the respective source code changes.

Answer (score 1):

The changelog is always up to date at https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt